# Implement FlexColorPicker

Tags: swift, swift5

I am looking for a Swift5 Color Picker and I came across the Color Picker of [Rastislav Mirek](https://github.com/RastislavMirek/FlexColorPicker).

I added the Picker as a Swift Package and followed the instructions in the Read Me file. For a simple start I wanted open the Color Picker as a modal and select a color. This color is set as a background then in the root view controller.
Even after having followed all steps I do not seem to get it working. I added the delegate and a button to trigger the segue to the modal.

Xcode drops an error like

- Use of undeclared type "ColorPickerDelegate"
  and
- Use of unresolved identifier "colorPickerController"

Does anyone have an hint for me?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ColorPickerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var hexTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func applyColorPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: colorPickerController)
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    }
}
```